# Definition of the tangential gradient

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open such that $\partial M$ is of class $C^1$ (i.e. a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$).

If $f:\partial M\to\mathbb R$ is $C^1$-differentiable, we can find the following definition of the "tangential gradient" of $f$ in [*Shapes and Geometries: Metrics, Analysis, Differential Calculus, and Optimization, Second Edition*](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719826) (p. 492)$^1$:

[image]

---

> Why is it important to consider a $C^1$-extension $F$ of $f$ on a **tubular** neighborhood (or even on that specific one)? Why can't we take *any* $C^1$-extension of $f$, i.e. any $\tilde f\in C^1(O)$, where $O$ is an $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood of $\partial M$, with $$f=\left.\tilde f\right|_{\partial M}?\tag1$$ Is it needed to show that $g(F)$ is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $F$? In any case, how can we show that it actually *is* well-defined?

**EDIT**: Meanwhile, I've found others references which consider arbitrary $C^1$-extensions. But it's still not clear to me why the definition of the tangential gradient is independent of the choice of the extension.

---

$^1$

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to restrict attention to a tubular neighborhood. Any $C^1$ extension to any neighborhood of $\partial \Omega$ will do.

Comment: The way to show $g(F)$ is well-defined is to use the result in the excerpt you quoted. If $F$ and $\widetilde F$ are two different extensions of $f$, then $F-\widetilde F$ vanishes on $\partial \Omega$, so its tangential derivatives are all zero. So when we subtract off the normal component of $\nabla(F-\widetilde F)$, we get zero.

Comment: A tubular neighborhood gives a canonical form of a neighborhood of any smooth submanifold. Other than that no clue why it's used there...

Comment: @JackLee But wouldn't that be true for any extension $\tilde f$ as in the question (satisfying $(1)$)?

Comment: @RachidAtmai Thank you for your comment. I guess you are referring to the "tubular neighborhood theorem". I've heard of that. In which sense is a tubular neighborhood "canonical"? And what's the problem with arbitrary neighborhoods? Is this an existence problem, i.e. are the tubular neighborhoods, in some situations, the only kind of neighborhoods which can be found?

Comment: @0xbadf00d it appears that the existence of such neiborhoods establishes a vector bundle structure which in return appears to be very useful to bring technology from algebraic topology and homology groups into the study of manifolds. It is therefore remarkable that such neighborhoods exist for manifolds as they help bring tools from other areas of mathematics to the study of manifolds. That's maybe a central intuition, though I'm no expert in the field, trying to learn myself

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, that's the point. The tangential gradient is going to be the same for any $C^1$ extension of $f$.  It doesn't matter whether you use a tubular neighborhood, or how you come up with the extension.

Comment: @JackLee The projection onto the tangent space $T_x\:\partial\Omega$ of $\partial\Omega$ at $x$ is precisely given by $\mathbb R^d\ni y\mapsto y-\langle y,n(x)\rangle n(x)$. So, the right-hand side of the definition of $g(F)(x)$ is precisely the projection of $\nabla F(x)$ onto $T_x\:\partial\Omega$. So, arguing that $g(F)(x)=0$ by saying that the tangential component of $\nabla F(x)$ vanishes, doesn't seem to make sense. So, how do we see this? Does it simply follow from $F(x)=0$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I don't understand your question. Why doesn't it make sense? The projection of $\nabla F(x)$ onto $T_x\partial\Omega$ is obtained by splitting $\nabla F(x)$ into tangential and normal components, and throwing away the normal component. If the tangential component is zero, then the projection is zero. And when $F$ vanishes identically on $\partial \Omega$, the tangential component is zero.

Comment: @JackLee Yes, it's trivial once we know that the tangential component is zero. But while it seems to be obvious to you, I don't get why $\left.F\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ implies that (which should mean $\nabla F(x)\in N_x\:\partial\Omega$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$).

Comment: @JackLee I'm not sure if this is what you've got in mind, but please take a look at my [(partial) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3786458/47771). Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Partial answer:

Consider the setting of my other question: [Does the pushforward of a smooth map on a manifold coincide with the derivative in a tangent direction of any local extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3786087/47771).

In that question, I've proven (hopefully without making any mistake) that if $v\in T_x\:M$ and $\gamma$ is a $C^1$-curve on $M$ through $x$ with $\gamma'(0)=v$, then $${\rm D}_vf(x):=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)\in T_{f(x)}\:E\tag2$$ is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $\gamma$. Moreover, if $\tilde f$ is a $C^1$-extension of $f$ at $x$, then $${\rm D}_vf(x)={\rm D}_v\tilde f(x)={\rm D}\tilde f(x)v\tag3.$$

We can immediately infer the following: If $h\in\mathbb R^d$, then $$h=v+w\tag4$$ for some unique $(v,w)\in T_x\:M\times N_x\:M$ and $${\rm D}_vf(x)={\rm D}\tilde f(x)(h-w)\tag5.$$

Turning to the situation of this question, assume $k=d-1$ and let $\Omega$ be an $M$-open neighborhood of $x$ which is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^k$. Then, $$w=\langle h,\nu_\Omega(x)\rangle\nu_\Omega(x)\tag6$$ and hence $${\rm D}_vf(x)={\rm D}\tilde f(x)h-\langle h,\nu_\Omega(x)\rangle{\rm D}\tilde f(x)\nu_\Omega(x)\tag7.$$ If $E=\mathbb R$, then we may rewrite this as $$\nabla_vf(x)=\nabla\tilde f(x)-\left\langle\nabla\tilde f(x),\nu_\Omega(x)\right\rangle\nu_\Omega(x)\tag8.$$ This is precisely the definition of the tangential gradient and by the former general reasoning we know that it is independent of the choice of $\tilde f$.

Comment: This is basically the right idea. But there are a couple of statements here that don't make sense in the context of your original question. In the question, $\Omega$ was an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ with $C^1$ boundary, but here you say "let $\Omega$ be an $M$-open neighborhood of $x$ which is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to $\mathbb H^k$." What is $M$? What is  $\mathbb H^k$? And what do you mean by an $M$-open neighborhood?

Comment: @JackLee Yeah, sorry, I ran into conflicting symbols with the other question. I've replaced the $\Omega$ in this question with $M$ so that this answer is clearer now. An $M$-open neighborhood of $x$ is an open subset of $M$ containing $x$.

Comment: @JackLee After my clarification, do you agree with my answer?

Comment: Again, I think you have the basic mathematical idea. But there are so many problems with what you've written that it's hard to say it's a "correct" answer. Part of the problem is that you've used some notations from the previous question that are either inconsistent with those in the current question, or undefined in the current question.

Comment: So try to answer these questions: _In the context of your current question_, what is $\mathbb H^n$? What is $E$? What is $h$? What is $w$? What is $\nu_\Omega(x)$? And then your final statement says "this is precisely the definition of the tangential gradient," but what you wrote is _not_ precisely the same as the definition you pasted into your original question. The last equation you wrote is an equation between real numbers, but the tangential gradient is a vector. How are they related?

Comment: $\mathbb H^n:=\mathbb R^{n-1}\times[0,\infty)$. $E$ is the codomain of $f$, which could generally be any $\mathbb R$-Banach space (in *this* question, $E=\mathbb R$). $h$ is defined in this answer, in the line immediately before equation $(4)$. $w$ is defined in equation $(4)$; it is the normal component of $h$ in the orthogonal decomposition $\mathbb R^d=T_x\:M⊕N_x\:M$. $ν_Ω$ is the unique unit outer normal field on $\partialΩ$. Regarding "this is precisely the definition of the tangential gradient": I'm sorry. Something went wrong when I partially copy-pasted from $(7)$. $(8)$ is fixed now.

Comment: Actually, I just realized there's an even more serious problem with your equation (8): the left-hand side is a real number, but the right-hand side is a vector.

Comment: @JackLee No, the left-hand side is a vector as well. What I denote by $\nabla_vf(x)$ is the vector in $\mathbb R^d$ satisfying ${\rm D}_vf(x)=\langle\nabla_vf(x),\;\cdot\;\rangle$.

Comment: @JackLee I'd still be interested in what you think.

Comment: Since the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb R^1$, I don't see how you're interpreting $\nabla_v f(x)$ as a vector in $\mathbb R^d$. It's a directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction $v$, which you can interpret either as a real number or as a tangent vector to $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: @JackLee But when we consider the ordinary gradient $\nabla f$, the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb R^1$ as well, isn't it? This is actually the important aspect, since then the Fréchet derivative maps into $\mathfrak (\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^1)\cong\mathbb R^d$. So, I'm not able to figure out where our misunderstanding lies, but please simply forget $(8)$. The important thing I want to know is whether you agree with $(7)$. $(8)$ the same equation as $(7)$, but under the identification $\mathfrak L(\mathbb Rd,\mathbb R^1)\cong\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Yes, (7) is fine.

Comment: @JackLee Please take a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/370403/91890). I think it is related (or even a special case of) Lemma 9.33 in your book.