What does the expression mean $u_{x_ix_j} = -f(0) v_i v_j $. (Nirenberg academic paper)
I am working on the following academic paper Symmetry and Related Properties
via the Maximum Principle, which is a classic by Louis Nirenberg. I am trying to understand the next lemma, which is on page 217. I have written the entire development  and I have understood it until I got to the end. I do not know how he arrives at that expression $u_{x_ix_j} = -f(0) v_i v_j \text{ at } x_0$ nor what interpretation it could have.
Important remark that for convenience the author write the next equality $u_{x_{i}}=u_{i}$.
Lemma 2.1.
Let $x_0 \in \Omega$ with $v_1(x_0) > 0$. For some $\epsilon > 0$, assume $u$ is a $C^2$ function in $\overline{\Omega}_{\epsilon}$ where $\Omega_{\epsilon}=\Omega \cap \{|x - x_0| < \epsilon\}$, $u > 0$ in $\Omega$, and $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega' \cap \{|x - x_0| < \epsilon\}$. Then there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that in $\Omega \cap \{|x - x_0| < \delta\}$, $u_{x_1} < 0$.
$\textbf{Proof.}$  Since $u > 0$ in $\Omega$, necessarily, $u_{x_1} < 0$ on $\partial \Omega' \cap \{|x - x_0| < \epsilon\} = S$, and hence $v_1 < 0$ on $S$, for $v_1 > 0$ everywhere there, which we may assume by decreasing $\epsilon$ if necessary.
If the lemma were false, there would be a sequence of points $x^j \rightarrow x_0$, with $u_{x_1}(x^j) \geq 0$. For large $j$, the interval in the $x_1$ direction going from $x^j$ to $\partial \Omega'$ hits $S$ at a point where $u_{1}\leq 0$. Consequently, by the theorem of the mean,
$$
u_{1}(x_0) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad u_{11}(x_0) = 0.
$$
\noindent Suppose $f(0) > 0$. Then in $\Omega$, $u$ satisfies
$$
\Delta u + b_1 u_{x_1} + f(u) - f(0) \leq 0,
$$
or, by the theorem of the mean, for some function $c_1(x)$,
$$
\Delta u + b_1 u_{x_1} + c_1(x) u \leq 0.
$$
Applying hopf lemma to the function $-u$, we find
$$
u_{x_{1}}(x_0) < 0 \quad \text{and so} \quad u_{1}(x_0)<0
$$
a contradiction.
Now, suppose $f(0) < 0$. From the equation (2.1), we see that at $x_0$, $\nabla u = 0$ and $\Delta u = -f(0)$. But then it follows that
$$
u_{x_ix_j} = -f(0) v_i v_j  \;\text{ at }\;  x_0.
$$
In particular, $u_{x_1x_1}(x_0) > 0$, again a contradiction. The lemma is proved.

First of all, you've mistakenly copied $\nu$ (i.e. the outward unit normal) as a $v$.
Consider the tangential gradient on $\partial \Omega$ defined by $\delta u = (\delta_1u , \dots,\delta_n u)$ where $$ \delta_i u (x) := \partial_i u(x) - (\nabla u(x) \cdot \nu(x)) \nu_i(x) \qquad\text{for all }x\in \partial\Omega$$ Here $\nabla u=(\partial_1u,\dots,\partial_n u)$ is the usual gradient in $\mathbb R^n$. The tangential gradient ends up being the same as the gradient on $\partial \Omega$ in the Riemannian geometry sense. In particular, the tangential gradient is intrinsic (only depends on $u\vert_{\partial\Omega}$).
From here onwards, I will use the summation convention. On one hand, since $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $\delta u$ is intrinsic, $$ \delta_iu=0 \text{ and } \delta_{ij}u=0 \text{ on }\partial\Omega.$$
On the other hand, \begin{align*}
0=\delta_{ij}u &= \delta_j \big (\partial_iu - (\nu_k\partial_k u)\nu_i \big )\\
&= \delta_j \partial_iu - \nu_i \delta_j(\nu_k\partial_k u)-(\nu_k\partial_k u)\delta_j\nu_i \\
&= \delta_j \partial_iu - \nu_i (\delta_j\nu_k)\partial_k u- \nu_i \nu_k\delta_j\partial_k u-(\nu_k\partial_k u)\delta_j\nu_i .
\end{align*} Since $\nabla u(x_0)=0$, this gives $$0=\delta_j \partial_iu - \nu_i \nu_k\delta_j\partial_k u \qquad\text{at }x_0$$ Next, unpacking the $\delta_j$, we have \begin{align*}
0&=  \partial_{ij}u - (\nu_\ell\partial_{i\ell}u)\nu_j - \nu_i \nu_k\big ( \partial_{jk} u - \nu_\ell \nu_j\partial_{k\ell}u\big)\\
&=\partial_{ij}u- \nu_\ell\nu_j\partial_{i\ell}u- \nu_i \nu_k \partial_{jk} u +  \nu_i \nu_k\nu_\ell \nu_j\partial_{k\ell}u.
\end{align*}  Moreover, using that $\delta_iu=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $\nabla u(x_0)=0$, we have $$ \partial_{i\ell}u = \partial_\ell \big (\delta_iu+ \nu_i\nu_k \partial_ku \big) =\nu_i\nu_k\partial_{k\ell}u  . $$ Hence, \begin{align*}
\partial_{ij}u &=\nu_\ell\nu_j\partial_{i\ell}u+ \nu_i \nu_k \partial_{jk} u -  \nu_i \nu_k\nu_\ell \nu_j\partial_{k\ell}u\\
&=\nu_i \nu_j\nu_k\nu_\ell \partial_{k\ell}u. 
\end{align*} This identity implies that $$ \Delta u = \vert \nu \vert^2\nu_k\nu_\ell \partial_{k\ell}u=\nu_k\nu_\ell \partial_{k\ell}u,$$ so we finally obtain the identity $$\partial_{ij}u =(\Delta u) \nu_i \nu_j \qquad \text{at }x_0.$$ Then $\Delta u(x_0)=-f(u(x_0))=-f(0)$ which completes the proof.

Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that the concept of tangential gradient existed in the form that you have written. I have seen that it does appear in other questions on the forum. I am reading your comment and trying to understand it. The nomenclature is a bit dense.

@Richard I’ve seen in it in this form a lot in geometric measure theory, so I totally agree that you can find references that are dense. If it helps, it’s actually exactly the covariant derivative that is taught in the geometry of surfaces - you take the usual gradient in $\mathbb R^n$ then project it into the tangent space by subtracting the component of the gradient in the direction of the normal

Ok, that final comment is key: " you take the usual gradient in $\mathbb{R}^n$
then project it into the tangent space by subtracting the component of the gradient in the direction of the normal" . I'm reading the book recommended in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783358/definition-of-the-tangential-gradient . I share the link in case it helps someone by reading this post
